# Laravel 8 ( with php 8.1 ) compiles Vue 2.6 into symbols

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-8

As the title says, my Laravel 8 is compiling Vue into weird symbols.
This is the output that I am getting:

```
=="" ""="">
```

[image]

The issue does not happen on the same project before the upgrade to PHP 8. I also updated Laravel files following [this guide](https://blog.laravel.com/laravel-php-8-support).

Here's my package.json file

```
{
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "mix",
    "watch": "mix watch",
    "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
    "hot": "mix watch --hot",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "mix --production"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "postcss": "^8.1.14",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "sass": "^1.32.11",
    "sass-loader": "^11.0.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.12",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.7",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12"
},
"dependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.27.4",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.0",
    "facebook-login-vuejs": "^2.1.3",
    "vue-facebook-login-component": "^4.0.2",
    "vuejs-datepicker": "^1.6.2"
}
}
```

There are multiple `.vue` files that I unfortunately cannot share, but compiling Vue before updating Laravel 8 was behaving correctly.

I have tried updating/downgrading packages, but that would result in me getting some dependecies errors related to versions or files not being found, and currently I am at a loss, having no idea what to do.

--
**Edit**: added mix file

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.setPublicPath('../assets/v2/')
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'js')
   .vue({

    })
.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'css');
mix.browserSync('http://localhost/');
```

**Edit:** added HTML output

```
<div id="app">
    =="" ""=""&gt;
</div>
```

This is all that appears in the div where Vue is used. And there's also no errors in the console.

Comment: And I am most certainly it's a Laravel issue. I have tried to copy the compiled app.js file from the old project (on which it worked) to the updated one, and it would still give the same output.

Comment: how does your mix file look like?

Comment: @Aless55 added it in the post

Comment: Consider posting HTML output instead of rendered page, it will be much more informative.

Comment: @EstusFlask added to post. The HTML output is, simply, just that. There are also no errors in the console or other things, that shouldn't be, added anywhere.